# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS wifi issues

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

Wifi doesn't see any networks, but wifi is on. After fresh install, I tried rebooting the wifi manager thing, but this doesn't help. I rebooted the computer, updated Ubuntu, reinstalled the wifi driver but nothing helps.

I am also new to Linux as a whole, so mainly I just googled this common issue, then looked it over. Did some commands and all but nothing at all helps

Computer information that was asked:

Integrated Bluetooth®1, WiMax2 & high-speed 802.11n Wi-Fi

Driver: ever showed up with one under additional drivers (ever had a driver pop up for wifi too on the 5 computers i put Ubuntu or any Linux on)

Full computer information:

- Up to 2nd generation Intel® Core™ i5 processor with
  Intel® Turbo Boost Technology 2.0
- Up to Genuine Windows® 7 Home Premium
- Lenovo Enhanced Experience 2.0 for Windows® 7 with
  RapidBoot technology – delivers faster start-up & shutdown and
  optimized multimedia capabilities
- 15.6” Backlit LED HD display (1366x768), 16:9 widescreen
- Up to NVIDIA® GeForce® GT540M 2GB graphics with DirectX® 11
- Up to 8GB DDR3 memory, up to 750GB HDD storage
- Integrated Bluetooth®1, WiMax2 & high-speed 802.11n Wi-Fi
- Integrated DVD reader/writer & Blu-ray Disc™1 drive
- USB2.0, eSATA connectors & 5in1 card-reader
- Integrated 0.3/2M (720p HD1) webcam

PS lol@ the random fixes by mod

Comment: Please update your question with computer make and model, WiFi card make and model and the driver name you installed.

Comment: Download the `Wireless Info Script` (probably with ethernet or from another pc with internet access) as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos (no need to execute the command, just download it from the link), then make it executable and execute it from the pc which has the problem. Put the results at http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and provide a link to your question. With this information we will be able to help you.

Comment: added more info to post :3